# Adding like terms for factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to factor the following identity:

$4a^3 + 8a^2b^2 - 4ab^2 - 2a^2b$

When I first look at this, I say to myself I obviously need to simplify it further, since I can spot a few like terms. I notice that 2a is divisible by all 4 numbers, thus:

$2a(2a^2 + 4ab^2 - 2b^2 - ab)$

What else should I do next?

Answer (score 4):

Next notice that $2a^2+4ab = 2a(2b+a)$ and $-2b^2-ab = -b(2b+a)$, so you can further simplify it as $$2a(2a(2b+a)-b(2b+a))=2a(2b+a)(2a-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Well my teacher said to us first try and see if there are any common factors for all terms(2a in this case) then look for any known formulas(sum/difference of cubes,difference of squares etc.),then try grouping them 2 by 2.
NOTE:for the comment below me you typed 4ab instead of 4ab^2